# Itertools groupby to organize list of dictionaries by two values

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm attempting to organize values by state of birth as well as if they have 0 money or not. Itertools groupby function looks like the simplest way to do so but I'm struggling implementing it. Open to other options as well.

If I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this

```
users = [
            {"name": "John", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Andrew", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 300},
            {"name": "Scott", "state_of_birth": "OR", "money": 20},
            {"name": "Travis", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Bill", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Mike", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0}
        ]
```

I'm attempting to get this output

```
desired_output = [
            [{"name": "John", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0}, {"name": "Bill", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0}],
            [{"name": "Andrew", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 300}],
            [{"name": "Scott", "state_of_birth": "OR", "money": 20}],
            [{"name": "Travis", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0},{"name": "Mike", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0}]
            ]
```

Comment: I don't see any code attempt here. Could you share that? Thanks. BTW, groupby is probably not going to work here. I'd create tuple keys into a defaultdict.

Comment: I have code that I used by looping through everything multiple times but thought it would just complicate the question for future viewers. Wasn't sure how to approach itertools.

Comment: No, it's better to show what you tried. Future users might see your code and think, wow, I'm doing the same thing and running  into the same problem -- how can I fix it? Then they scroll to the answer. Without that, context is pretty much a mystery to everyone. Adding code also helps clarify intent and your specification, although it seems pretty clear here. It's generally more instructive to have someone walk through a non-working attempt than just hand the answer from scratch, making assumptions that might not be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` like this:

```py
import itertools

def func(x):
    return tuple([x['state_of_birth'], x['money'] != 0])

desired_output = list(list(v) for _,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(users, key=func), func))
```

`group_by` function is a generator that produces `key` and `value`. The key is derived from the `key_function` that we're passing to the `itertools.groupb_by()`. In your case, having the `keys` in not important, that's why it is ignore in `for _, v`.

Output:

```py
[{'name': 'John', 'state_of_birth': 'CA', 'money': 0}, {'name': 'Bill', 'state_of_birth': 'CA', 'money': 0}]
[{'name': 'Andrew', 'state_of_birth': 'CA', 'money': 300}]
[{'name': 'Travis', 'state_of_birth': 'NY', 'money': 0}, {'name': 'Mike', 'state_of_birth': 'NY', 'money': 0}]
[{'name': 'Scott', 'state_of_birth': 'OR', 'money': 20}]
```

Comment: see the expected output and you are also not using `money` key also

Comment: @deadshot You're right. Now money is considered

Comment: the outer tuple() call and [] in the function don't have to be there, do they? Would `return (x['state_of_birth'], x['money'] != 0)` be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you have a structure that is `List[Dict]` and you want to get a `List[List[Dict]]` where the inner list contain dictionaries that have the same `state_of_birth` and `money > 0` boolean.

I would say the easiest solution is actually to use `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

users = [
            {"name": "John", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Andrew", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 300},
            {"name": "Scott", "state_of_birth": "OR", "money": 20},
            {"name": "Travis", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Bill", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Mike", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0}
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(users)

# we need a column to indicate if money > 0
df["money_bool"] = df["money"] > 0

# groupby gives you an iterator of Tuple[key, sub-dataframe]
# dfs now holds a list of your grouped dataframes
dfs = [tup[1] for tup in df.groupby(["state_of_birth", "money_bool"])]

# you can now drop the money_bool column if you want
dfs = [df.drop("money_bool", axis=1) for df in dfs]

desired_output = [df.to_dict("records") for df in dfs]
```

Depending on the context of the problem, you may be better off staying in dataframe/tabular format

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the input to the `groupby` function is sorted. You can use the same key function as for grouping:

```
users = [
            {"name": "John", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Andrew", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 300},
            {"name": "Scott", "state_of_birth": "OR", "money": 20},
            {"name": "Travis", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Bill", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
            {"name": "Mike", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0}
        ]

def selector(item): return (item.get('state_of_birth'), item.get('money') != 0)
sorted_users = sorted(users, key=selector)
result = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted_users, selector) ]
```

Output:

```
[
    [{'name': 'John', 'state_of_birth': 'CA', 'money': 0}, {'name': 'Bill', 'state_of_birth': 'CA', 'money': 0}],
    [{'name': 'Andrew', 'state_of_birth': 'CA', 'money': 300}], 
    [{'name': 'Travis', 'state_of_birth': 'NY', 'money': 0}, {'name': 'Mike', 'state_of_birth': 'NY', 'money': 0}],
    [{'name': 'Scott', 'state_of_birth': 'OR', 'money': 20}]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although its name seems like it should be the way to go, `itertools.groupby` is not the correct function to use because it requires the data to be pre-sorted. Sorting brings your time complexity to O(n log(n)) for an algorithm that should be O(n).

To put that in perspective, if you have a million records to sort, instead of a million iterations, you now have 20 million iterations if you use `groupby` instead of a loop and dict. That's a pretty significant performance penalty.

If `groupby` was cleaner to write or didn't have an import, it might be justifiable, but it's less readable than a simpler approach using a plain loop and dictionary.

Pandas is fine, but there's really no reason to use it unless you're already doing so. It's like bringing in a space shuttle to grill a zucchini.

You can use `defaultdict` and a loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

users = [
    {"name": "John", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
    {"name": "Andrew", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 300},
    {"name": "Scott", "state_of_birth": "OR", "money": 20},
    {"name": "Travis", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0},
    {"name": "Bill", "state_of_birth": "CA", "money": 0},
    {"name": "Mike", "state_of_birth": "NY", "money": 0},
]

grouped = defaultdict(list)
groupby = "state_of_birth", "money"

for user in users:
    grouped[tuple([user[k] for k in groupby])].append(user)

pprint([*grouped.values()])
```

If you want "money is nonzero" rather than just the `"money"` value itself, you can use a custom grouping function:

```
grouped = defaultdict(list)

def group_by(x):
    return x["state_of_birth"], x["money"] != 0

for user in users:
    grouped[group_by(user)].append(user)

result = [*grouped.values()]
```

or inline the logic:

```
grouped = defaultdict(list)

for user in users:
    grouped[user["state_of_birth"], user["money"] != 0].append(user)

result = [*grouped.values()]
```